# Comparar datos entre dos array en php

Tags: php, php7, php5

Estoy bastante trabado al querer comparar datos de dos array.

Por ejemplo:

```
$array1 = [1, 2, 3 ,4, 5];
$array2 = [2, 5, 4, 0, 1];
```

Yo lo que tengo que hacer es imprimir los datos que son idénticos entre dos arrays.

Comment: ¿Comprar o comparar?

Comment: [`array_intersect`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php) te trae los valores que están en ambos arrays

Comment: ¿Cómo determinas si son idénticos? ¿Por que los valores que contienen ambos arreglos son los mimos o por que coinciden en cada posición?

Answer (score 3):

La función `array_intersect()` hace precisamente eso, retorna un array que contiene los valores que están presentes en los otros arrays que le pasemos.

Ejemplo:

```
$array1 = [1, 2, 3 ,4, 5];
$array2 = [2, 5, 4, 0, 1];

$coincidencias = array_intersect($array1, $array2);

foreach($coincidencias as $value) {
    echo $value;
}

// Resultado:  1245
```

Documentación https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-intersect.php

Answer (score 0):

Puedes comparar uno con foreach

```
foreach($array1 as $item) {
    if(in_array($item, $array2) {
        echo $item;
    }
}
```